# schtasks : ERROR: Incorrect Start Date

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I am using "schtasks" to create a task in the windows task Scheduler. Below is the command that am using.

```
"SchTasks /Create /TN CRM_TELESMART_ICE /TR "perl D:\Serviont\LSS-Phase2\hdfc_Perl\bin\common_processing.pl --sourcename CRM_TELESMART_ICE --type DB" /SD 06/23/2016 /ST 12:38 /SC MINUTE /MO 20 /F "
```

Here the problem is, when I run this java file it executes well and creates a task in local machine. In server it is showing the below error.

> Process exiting with code: -2147467259
>
> ERROR: Incorrect Start Date.

I tried to create the same via a standalone java application it is working in server too. The only problem is, when calling through the production application.

Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Old question I know but have you tried using a sensible date such as 23/06/2016? Possibly the regional settings in your Java file are set to something other than American somehow.